# Updating a dependency property based on changes in the view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, dependency-properties

I'm having some problems with data binding in WPF. Here's the scenario: I have made a user control which simulates a Dial Pad (i.e., an array of 12 buttons with the digits from '0' to '9' plus the '#' and 'Clear' keys). The control lives inside a class library and it's been implemented following the MVVM pattern, mainly because I need the components in the class library to be easily unit tested.

The view model for the control is quite simple, it basically updates a public "DialedNumber" string (which is internally connected to the model) every time the user presses a dial pad key button. The binding is working correctly and, by using the debugger, I can confirm that the "DialedNumber" variable inside the viewmodel is getting updated as I press button in the dial pad.

This DialPad control is used by a separate XAML file (Panel.xaml), which laids out several controls that belong to my custom class library.

Now, I'd like to add a TextBlock inside my Panel file in order to display the "DialedNumber" string held inside the DialPad. This is the code snippet in Panel.xaml:

```
<PanelControls:DialPad x:Name="MyDialPad" DialedNumber="55325"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyDialPad, Path=DialedNumber}" />
```

The result I'm getting is that the textblock displays the correct number on start (i.e., "55325"), but its content doesn't get updated as I press the dial pad keys (even though the DialPad's viewmodel gets updated as I press new keys, as I've checked with the debugger).

Here's the code behind for the DialPad view:

```
public partial class DialPad : UserControl
{
    public DialPad()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new DialPadViewModel();
    }

    public void DialedNumberChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        return;
    }

    public DialPadViewModel DialPadViewModel
    {
        get { return DataContext as DialPadViewModel; }
    }

    public string DialedNumber
    {
        get
        {
            var dialPadViewModel = Resources["DialPadVM"] as DialPadViewModel;
            return (dialPadViewModel != null) ? dialPadViewModel.DialedNumber : "";
        }
        set
        {
            var dialPadViewModel = Resources["DialPadVM"] as DialPadViewModel;
            if (dialPadViewModel != null)
            {
                dialPadViewModel.DialedNumber = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the DialPad view model:

```
public class DialPadViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public DialPadViewModel()
    {
        _dialPadModel = new DialPadModel();
    }

    #region Fields

    private readonly DialPadModel _dialPadModel;
    private ICommand _dialPadKeyPressed;

    #endregion

    #region Public Properties/Command

    public DialPadModel DialPadModel
    {
        get { return _dialPadModel; }
    }

    public ICommand DialPadKeyPressedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_dialPadKeyPressed == null)
            {
                _dialPadKeyPressed = new RelayCommand(DialPadKeyPressedCmd);
            }
            return _dialPadKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    public string DialedNumber
    {
        get { return _dialPadModel.DialedNumber; }
        set
        {
            _dialPadModel.DialedNumber = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DialedNumber");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Helpers

    private void DialPadKeyPressedCmd(object parameter)
    {
        string keyPressedString = parameter.ToString();

        if (keyPressedString.Length > 0)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(keyPressedString[0]))
            {
                DialedNumber += keyPressedString[0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else if (keyPressedString == "C" || keyPressedString == "Clr" || keyPressedString == "Clear")
            {
                DialedNumber = "";
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Let me restate my problem: the textblock in Panel.xaml displays the correct number (55325) on start, but its value never gets updated as I press the DialPadButtons. I've placed a breakpoint inside DialPadKeyPressedCmd and I can confirm that the method gets executed everytime I press a key in the dial pad.

Comment: Try setting the Source to Source = DialPadViewModel ....because you are specifying the DialedNumber property via the Path.

Comment: @colinsmith: I tried that but I had no luck. The command bound to the buttons get invoked and the viewmodel/model get updated, but the dependency property located in the view doesn't get the new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place your DialPad in your View, you can create a DialPadViewModel-Property (public+global) in your ViewViewModel:

```
public DialPadViewModel DialPadViewModel = new DialPadViewModel();
```

Now set the DataContext-Binding of your View to the ViewViewModel and bind the DialPads DataContext also to it, like

```
<local:DialPad DataContext="{Binding}"/>
```

Now you can bind to the properties in your DialPadViewModel:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber}"/>
```

Thats how you can Access your DialPadViewModel from your View and your DialPad.

EDIT:

Now try changing your DialedNumber Property in your DialPad.xaml.cs like this:

```
public string DialedNumber
{
    get
    {
        return DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber;
    }
    set
    {
        DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber = value;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: I found the Problem:

In your DialPad.xaml all your Commands were bound to the DialPadViewModel from the resources, while the TextBloc was bound to the DialPads DataContext, which is another instance of the DialPadViewModel.

So everytime you hit a DialPad-Button you changed the value of the DialedNumber from the resources' DPVM-instance not the DialedNumber from the DataContext's DPVM-instance.

Comment: Yes, I've already done all that. The problem I'm experiencing is how can I reflect changes in the view that have been performed inside the viewmodel.

Comment: Everytime PropertyChanged("DialedNumber"); is called, the binding will update automatically, even the binding in the view. So place this call wherever you want in your DialPadViewModel. Or do you change DialedNumber in your ViewViewModel?

Comment: That's right, I'm changing DialedNumber in the ViewModel as a result of pressing the dial pad key buttons. How can I update the DialedNumber property of the view based on the changes that take place in the DialedNumber variable located in the view model?

Comment: Could you post the code where you change the DialedNumber property in the ViewModel?

Comment: Yes, no problem. I've updated my original post and included the snippet you requested. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Comment: 1. If all your buttons of the DialPad are on the DialPadView, why do you have a DialPadKeyPressedCmd() method in your ViewModel? 2. Do you have a RaisePropertyChanged("DialedNumber") method in the setter of the DialedNumber Property of your DialPadViewModel? If yes, try the following binding: Text="{Binding Path=_dialPadModel.DialedNumber}" and remove RaisePropertyChanged("DialedNumber"); of the DialedNumber-setter in your ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding the first question, I put that inside my ViewModel because it's business logic and I want it decoupled from the view so that I can test it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to replay to that part. I tested it (see the code at the bottom of my original message, which I have just edited), but it's still not working. It compiles and I don't get any runtime error, but the only TextBlock that displays a value is the first one.

Comment: Is _dialPadModel a private field? If thats the case, change it to a public property. So if the first TextBox displays a value, your problem is solved, isnt it?

Comment: I would prefer not to expose the model as public from the modelview. I'd rather expose only the necessary bits (like DialedNumber). The first TextBox displays the original value as defined in the XAML (i.e., 551), but it never gets updated based on my keypresses.

Comment: Then my Suggestion wont work. It doesnt update, even if you have RaisePropertyChanged("DialedNumber") in the setter of the DialedNumber-property in your ViewModel?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I have the RaisePropertyChanged call but the number won't update. It will only display the first value of "551", which gets assigned through the XAML, but it won't update based on my keypresses. Any ideas? I'm finding all this very disheartening.

Comment: Do you call DialPadKeyPressedCmd() everytime a Key of your DialPad is pressed?

Comment: I do, yes. I can confirm that's working because I've placed a breakpoint inside the DialPadKeyPressedCmd() method and it's hitting it consistently.

Comment: And why do you have a DependencyProperty DialedNumber also in the code-behind of your View (xaml.cs)? Your TextBox.Text-Property is bound to the DialedNumber of your ViewModel, isnt it? So this DependencyProperty should be redundant.

Comment: I've removed the DependencyProperty. Now in my view's code behind I have a public DialedNumber field with a getter/setter that reads/writes the DialedNumber field in the viewmodel. I also have a public DialPadViewModel field in the code behind that returns the DataContext as a casted DialPadViewModel. This is my XAML file: <PanelControls:DialPad x:Name="MyDialPad" DialedNumber="5535"/>            
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyDialPad, Path=DialedNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" /> Now the textblock displays the correct value on start (5535) but it doesn't get updated, any ideas?

Comment: Did you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface and do you call the PropertyChanged-Event in the setter of this DialedNumber-Property (which updates the DialedNumber in the DialPadViewModel)? Or you bind the DialedNumber Property of your DialPadViewModel to your TextBox by Path=DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber

Comment: Yes, I've implemented that interface in the DialPadViewModel and I'm calling "RaisePropertyChanged" in the DialedNumber setter. I'm also binding the DialedNumber property to the texbox as you've described. Maybe I should start a new question and post all the updated information and source code in there?

Comment: No, I think a new question will be removed. But you should update this question (remove old code and refresh the ViewModel, DialPadViewModel, xaml and xaml.cs).

Comment: OK, I've edited the whole question with the updated information. Hopefully my problem and the current state of my code is going to make a lot more sense now! Thank for all your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Bind to your DialedNumber Property of your DialPadViewModel, not your DialPad: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(NameOfDialPadViewModelInViewModelOfDataContextOfPanel.xaml).DialedNumber}" /> or raise the PropertyChanged-Event in the setter of your DialedNumber Property in the DialPad-UserControl.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I feel we're getting close to sort this out! I've replaced the TextBlock definition in the Panel.xaml with the following code: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber}" />. Now I'm not even getting the initial value (55325) on startup. I also don't understand when you say "or raise the Property...", does it mean I should either do the binding in Panel.xaml or raise the event, but not at the same time? Also, are you saying I should raise the PropertyChanged event from the code-behind? Sorry for the silly questions, but I'm quite new to WPF.

Comment: This means, that you should only raise the event in the properties which are bound to your controls. Before, your DialPad DialedNumber-Property was bound to the TextBlock but the PropertyChanged Event was in your DialedNumber Property of your DialPadViewModel, so you had to either change the binding or change the location of the PropertyChanged Event. Does your Panel.xaml have a DataContext? The binding (Text="{Binding Path=DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber}") does only work if your ViewModel of your Panel.xaml has a DialPadViewModel-Property.

Comment: OK, I think that I'm starting to understand what you say about the binding. I think it's better for me to leave the PropertyChanged event in the viewmodel, no need to overcomplicate it. Regarding your second question: my Panel.xaml doesn't have a DataContext, how do I set it?

Comment: Before doing this, try the following: <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MyDialPad, Path=DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber}" />

Comment: I've just tried it and no success: the textblock doesn't even get the DialedNumber value on startup (it doesn't display any value at all). No value is displayed either after punching the buttons in the DialPad, either.

Comment: See my edit. If this doesnt work you also could send me your solution and I have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I changed the code behind file but it's still now working: I get the correct value on startup but the display doesn't get updated as I punch new buttons. I'll gladly send you my solution, can I send you an e-mail with a rar file? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, send it to flog_@hotmail.de

Comment: Excellent, many thanks! I've sent you an e-mail a couple of minutes ago.

Comment: Everytime Im trying to send you the email with the corrected version, the delivery fails. So I edited my answer with the solution of your problem.

Comment: Thank you buddy! That fixed my problem. Plus, I've learnt something new about WPF.

Answer (score 2):

DependencyProperties are meant to point to some other property to get their value. So you can either point it to your `DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber`, or you can point it to some other string when the UserControl is used (either a binding or a hardcoded value like "551"), but you can't do both.

In your case, when someone binds to the `DialedNumber` dependency property, they are replacing the current value (the binding to `DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber`) with a new value.

Depending on how your code looks and what you want to do, there are a few ways around it.

First, you could insist that people who want to use your control also use your ViewModel, and don't make `DialedNumber` a public dependency property.

So instead of being allowed to create a custom class with a property of `SomeOtherDialedNumber` and binding

```
<DialPad DialedNumber="{Binding SomeOtherDialedNumber}">
```

they are forced to use the `DialPadViewModel` in their code anytime they want to use the DialPad control. For this to work, you would need to remove the `this.DataContext = new DialPadViewModel` in your code-behind the UserControl since the user will be providing the `DialPadViewModel` to your UserControl, and you can use an implicit DataTemplate to tell WPF to always draw `DialPadViewModel` with your `DialPad` UserControl.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type DialPadViewModel}">
    <local:DialPad />
</DataTemplate>
```

The other alternative I can think of is to synchronize your DependencyProperty with your ViewModel property with some PropertyChange notifications.

You would need to update `DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber` anytime the `DialedNumber` dependency property changes (You may need to use [DependencyPropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.addvaluechanged.aspx) for property change notification), and you would also have to write something to update the source of the `DialedNumber` dependency property anytime `DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber` changes.

Personally, if my UserControl has a ViewModel then I use the first option. If not, I get rid of the ViewModel entirely and build the logic for my UserControl in the code-behind, without a ViewModel.

The reason for this is that WPF works with two layers: a UI layer and a data layer. The `DataContext` is the data layer, and a ViewModel is typically part of the data layer. By setting the data layer (`DataContext`) explicitly in the UserControl's constructor, you are combining your data layer with your UI layer, which goes against one of the biggest reasons for using MVVM: separation of concerns. A UserControl should really just be a pretty shell only, and you should be able to place it on top of any data layer you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! At some point in your answer you said "and you would also have to write something to update the source of the DialedNumber dependency property anytime DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber changes.". That's exactly what I need to achieve, but I don't know how to achieve it. I have already figured out how to communicate changes from DialedNumber to DialPadViewModel.DialedNumber, but I don't know how to do it the other way around. How can I update my view based on a state change in the viewmodel?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can add a TextBox to your view and bind it's Text property to your view-model's DialedNumber property.

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DialedNumber}"></TextBox>
```

Your view-model property can look something like this:

```
    private string _dialedNumber;
    [DefaultValue("551")]
    public string DialedNumber
    {
        get { return _dialedNumber; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _dialedNumber)
                return;
            _dialedNumber= value;
            _yourModel.DialedNumber= _dialedNumber;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DialedNumber");
        }
    }
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I did that, but the problem I have is a little bit move involved. Basically my viewmodel is being updated everytime I press the dial pad buttons, but I don't know how can I feed the updated state information to the view.

Comment: This should work.  Make sure your view control's  binding mode is twoway...Mode=TwoWay.  Also, you're returning the value from your model in the DialedNumber property.  Make sure it has a value.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I think my problem boils down to how can I feed the updates in the DialedNumber located in the ViewModel all the way up to the view and the dependency property, so that the text box can pick up the changes. Is there a clean way to feed information from the viewmodel back to the view?

Comment: The easiest way is to have your view's textbox bound to the property in it's viewmodel - just as I posted in my answer.  In your viewmodel, your DialedNumber property must have RaisePropertyChanged("DialedNumber") - like you do.  That's it, no need for anything else.  As the DialedNumber gets updated, it will be reflected in the view.

Comment: I've updated my original post so that I can show you what I've tried (see at the bottom of my post). Still no luck, though!

Comment: What happens if you remove ElementName=MyDialPad from your control?  Also, try removing the DependencyProperty.

Comment: But if I remove the "ElementName=MyDialPad", how does the TextBlock know where to retrieve the property from? Also, if I remove the dependency property, how will I be able to assign a default number to it (e.g., "551") inside the XAML?

Comment: Because your viewmodel is bound to your view via the view's datacontext.  See my updated answer.

Comment: OK, yes, I've removed the dependency property and the default value (i.e., the one assigned via the XAML is still working). What I don't understand is how can I bind my TextBlock to the DialPad without using the "ElementName=MyDialPad". How does the textblock know where to get the DialedNumber field from?

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I meant: "I've removed the dependency property and the default value (i.e., the one assigned via the XAML) is still working".

Comment: Your view is bound to a view-model, so the view's controls will reflect the changes made to the view-model properties they are bound to...Text="{Binding Path=DialedNumber}".  It's this simple, don't over complicate it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Big Daddy. I understand, I can see that the DialPad view is bound to its view model. Revisiting my previous posts, I see I haven't emphasized the fact that the panel and the text block I'd like to associate with belong to a separate XAML file (let's call it Panel.xaml). So I have a Panel view that makes use of a DialPad and a text block in order to display the dialed number (the text block is not being placed in the DialPad view). That's why I don't understand how can I make the binding between the two without explicitly referencing an ElementName.

Comment: Big Daddy: I've edited the whole question with the updated information. Hopefully my problem and the current state of my code is going to make a lot more sense now! Thank for all your help, I really appreciate it!